# Responsive semantic ui grid with form not working

Tags: responsive-design, semantic-ui

I am working on the form that I would like when on Mobile the fields not to stack. When I resize my browser everything seems to be responsive, and working exactly like I want it...

However when I actually look at on a Mobile phone, it looks super tiny, just like a shrunk down screen.

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

First try to resize on browser, then look at on Mobile. 
https://billpay.solutions/test

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
add this line in your <head> tag
```